# Why do I see repetitive "GET / 404" in my node js console log?

Tags: node.js, express, http-status-code-404, console.log, morgan

```
GET / 404 0.658 ms - 13
GET / 404 0.464 ms - 13
GET / 404 0.313 ms - 13
GET / 404 0.416 ms - 13
GET / 404 0.393 ms - 13
GET / 404 0.202 ms - 13
GET / 404 0.124 ms - 13
GET / 404 0.142 ms - 13
```

404 - does this mean some thing is wrong? Or is there someone continuously trying to open a non-existent page? The site is www.AgileReady.org

Comment: Do you not have a route handler for `/`?  That's what the browser would request if someone just typed in your domain name by itself.

Comment: Not sure, I am quite new to node. Web site root works. www.agileready.org, does that not mean that there is router handler for "/"

Comment: Well, those log messages look like your server is reporting a 404 error when the root path is requested.  I doubt we can help you in any concrete way without seeing your actual server routing code.  On the surface, I'd say that yes something is probably wrong because there should not be 404 errors for a known path that you intend to support.